# How to find path of file by file name in python

Tags: python, path, operating-system

is there any way to find file path not in same dir of project by file name only

I don't want to save file to project dir and use it .

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath?

Comment: This would need to search all directories where the file could be.

Comment: how could i search all dirs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48393588/4788546 might help.

Comment: @Khalid You could use *find* on any \*nix type system. There may be an equivalent on Windows. You could also *os.walk()* from the root directory (\*nix) or, on Windows, I guess you'd need to figure out what drive letters are "in play" then walk those

Answer (score 0):

You can use the os module, which provides several functions for interacting with the file system.

```
import os

filename = "my_file.txt"
# Search in <search_path>
search_path = "C:/Users/MyUserName/Documents"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(search_path):
    if filename in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        print(f"The path of {filename} is {file_path}")
```

The *os.walk()* function traverse the directory tree rooted at *search_path*.

If we find the file, we can use the *os.path.join()* function to concatenate the directory path with the file name, giving us the full path to the file.